# How to access Method Names from source object in Rule Definition

Tags: rule-engine, business-rules, codeeffects

In our implementation of the Rules Engine we have a test form similar to Rule Test Form on the online demo on "Business Rules Engine Demo".  What we would like to do is conditionally show only the Test Fields for the items in use in the rule.  We are doing this by grabbing the rule.definition JSON from the ruleeditor then look for the items which we can conditionally create using AngularJS's ng-if directive.  This works great with Fields.  If the user selects a method, our method of parsing the string is failing.  What it appears is the Field Names are stored in the JSON as plain text however the Method Names are not.  Is there a way we can configure the control to either A not encrypt the method names or is there a way that we can tap into the encryption to identify if a method is in use in our rule?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Methods and actions can have overloads which the Code Effects rule editor supports. Therefore, we can't have multiple menu entries with the same name. Instead, we use a signature hash on all in-rule methods and rule actions regardless of whether it has an overload or not to make them unique on the client.

You need to have either the Full Source or the Editor Source license in order to change the code to either stop that hashing, or tap into the process, or implement it your own way. You don't have that option with any other Code Effects perpetual license.